# How to view/access database data in dashDB?

Tags: database, twitter, ibm-cloud, dashdb

How do you view and access database data in dashDB to show it in a different web page? I'm using Insights for Twitter to analyze the data on a Web-based app.

Comment: What do you mean with "in a different web page"? Please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

You can just use any of the Bluemix app containers and the standard JDBC driver package of dashDB to access the data from your app. E.g. you can start with this boilerplate https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/java-db-web-starter/ and drop the SQL DB service of it and bind dashDB instead. The JDBC driver is then already in place because it's the same like for SQL DB.